# Selecionar elemento pai com javascript (sem Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho dois elementos e gostaria de selecionar o elemento pai utilizando somente Javascript, alguém conhece alguma forma?

```
<tr>
    <td id="filho"><td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Utilize `parentNode`:
[Node.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)

```js
var filho = document.getElementById("filho");
var pai = filho.parentNode;

console.log(pai);
```

```html
<div id="pai">
  Sou Pai
  <div id="filho">
    Sou filho do meu pai :D
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a propriedade `parentNode`

Ex:

```
document.getElementById('filho').parentNode
```